# Close dialog UI bug

Tags: support, user-interface, close-dialog

I wonder if this has been reported yet?

This is what the close dialog looks like normally:

> [image: 1]

And this is what it looks like with a very long string entered:

> [image: 2]

The dialog contents seem to have scrolled off the left side. I found this when I copy-pasted a very long question URL.

Comment: This has been reported a couple times before, but I can't find either of them right now...

Comment: Uhh.. don't enter long strings? :)

Comment: @animuson Are you thinking of the same bounty box issue?

Comment: Ah, given my textual description I didn't think a freehand whatever-that-shape-is would be required to draw attention to the relevant portion of the screenshot! @Undo: Heh, I'm sure that advice (just don't trigger it!) holds true for most any bug. ;)